# Setting up : Spring boot + jpa + postgresql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

after searching for a long time i can't figure out how to work with spring-boot and postgresql.
Spring-boot is starting without warnings. 
The postgres server is running, but i dont know if spring-boot can access it.
Are the following files right ?

pom.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=db
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Frame implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String raw;
  private String time;
  private double tempRad;
  private double tempAirIn;
  private double tempAirOut;

  public Frame(String time, double tempRad, double tempAirIn, double tempAirOut){
    this.time = time;
    this.tempRad = tempRad;
    this.tempAirIn = tempAirIn;
    this.tempAirOut = tempAirOut;
  }
.
.
.
```

Application.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrameServiceImpl frameServiceImpl = new FrameServiceImpl();
        int lower = 12;
        int higher = 29;
        for(int i = 0; i > 10000; i++){
            frameServiceImpl.save(new Frame(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(i).toString(),
                (Math.random() * (higher-lower)) + lower,
                (Math.random() * (higher-lower)) + lower,
                (Math.random() * (higher-lower)) + lower));

        }
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("Server started.");
    }

}
```

RestController :

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private FrameRepository frameRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/findall")
    public String findAll(){
        String result = "";
        int i = 0;

        for(Frame f : frameRepository.findAll()){
            result += i + " : " + f.toString() + "</br>";
            i++;
        }

        return "result : " + result;
    }
}
```

[Postgresql server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvzsY.jpg)

[From the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtMFm.jpg)

[EDIT]
Now Working.
- FrameServiceImpl needed @Component to be @Autowired
- @Autowired component doesn't work in the main function (static)
- @Autowired the FrameServiceImpl, dont instantiate it.

Comment: You could just add a couple of records to your frames table and look whether you see them in your controller output.

Comment: The "frame" table is empty and i don't know why. spring boot should set it up (see "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update"). you mean add them  manually. I will try.

Comment: You were right. 
I added manually 2 lines to the db and i can see them in the browser.
So my problem is saving them in the db.

Answer (score 6):

**In properties file I did this;**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=db
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

**and in pom;**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```